# How to eliminate keynote to take over the whole screen in slideshow mode

Tags: macos, slideshow, fullscreen, keynote

We are building a Desktop app which has to activate keynote application on desktop automatically in slideshow mode.

The problem is that the slideshow is taking over the whole screen.

Is there a way to control the size of the keynote window in slideshow mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SIMBL package and hook the functions of the window related to the full screen. You may use class dump to figure out what is going on in the Keynote app. However, you will meet another problems - your window is still without menu, you will be forced to handle resize events, etc.